# Foundation 5 for Rails on Heroku Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

I am building a new website on Rails and was able to successfully install the new Foundation 5 gem locally.  When I pushed it to Heroku I have been getting the following message:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find foundation-rails-5.0.0 in any of the sources
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find foundation-rails-5.0.0 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Any ideas where I should go from here?  Is there something I need to do on my end or is this on Heroku's end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few versions of the gem [were yanked](http://rubygems.org/gems/foundation-rails/versions).

Make sure your Gemfile points to a version 5.0.1.0 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and it's also been noted on Foundation's forum. The foundation-rails gem is pretty new (I just now updated to 5.0.2) and it still tanks. Probably just a matter of time until Heroku/Zurb work out the kinks.